# How can I change the default location Snipping Tool auto-saves screenshots to?

Tags: windows, screenshot, snipping-tool, autosave

When you open the Windows Snipping Tool using <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, it will autosave the images to `%UserProfile%\Pictures\Screenshots`, but I want to change that default location.

How can I change the default save location for the snipping tool only, and not anything else?

- There's a ton of threads about this on Microsoft forums, but none actually offer a solution:

  - [How to change the Snipping Tool autosave location?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-change-the-snipping-tool-autosave-location/59424fed-2c67-4b2e-a328-310459934ab6) [sic]
  - [Change Snipping Tool save location on Windows 11 22H2?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/change-snipping-tool-save-location-on-windows-11/0801a2aa-276f-4e9b-afac-b00efc61a403) [sic]
  - [How can I change the default folder that snipping tool uses to save images?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-can-i-change-the-default-folder-that-snipping/e07becc8-2a71-4e78-ba4b-b882aafce479)

Comment: Please use correct markdown formatting for weblinks _(please see the formatting bar for the "link" button)_ and other markdown

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem and think I solved it - you can either use the Snipping Tool app to find the current default save location and change it, or you can update the registry key for it manually.

### Using the Snipping Tool app

1. Open the Snipping Tool → Expand the Menu → *Open Screenshots folder*

   [image: Scerno snipping tool menu screenshots folder]

   - If not seeing this option, turn on `Automatically save screenshots` via `Settings`
2. This will open the default save location in File Explorer.  One way to change the default location it saves to, is to edit this folder - if you rename or move this folder, Snipping Tool automatically updates the location path:

   - For example, it currently saves images to `%UserProfile%\Images\Screenshots`, and if I move and rename this to `%UserProfile\Documents\Test`, all new screenshots will be saved to the new location

---

### Edit Registry Key

If you're stuck on this and need to make manual changes, you can edit the save location through the Registry Editor:

1. Start Menu Search: `regedit` → Open `regedit` → Navigate to key:

   ```
   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
   ```
2. You'll find a `string value` entry similar to `{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}`, which contains the save location for the Snipping Tool - for me it's:

   ```
   %UserProfile%\OneDrive - <myname>\PC Files\Images\Screenshots
   ```

   [image: Scerno registry editor keys]

   - If the Registry key doesn't exist, create it manually to do the same thing
3. Open this key to change the save location manually - once saved, it takes effect immediately - taking a new screenshot will save it to the new location

   - If creating the key manually fails, the `Screenshots` folder may be named slightly differently.  To find the correct name, you'll need to navigate to this key in the Registry Editor:

     ```
     HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\
     ```

- Find a subkey that has a `Name` entry with Value of `Screenshots` (green), copy the name of this key (orange), and use this name in place of the name suggested above *(this key name will match the Value name for the `Screenshots` save location)*:

  [image: Scerno screenshot of registry editor]

Comment: Awesome. Works great.